# hash collisions between hg/mercurial and git?

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm pondering to use the same db model to represent git and hg changesets in a mixed set up. That'd allow me to just store git-vs-hg in the repos.

I'm wondering, are there known overlaps between the hg and git algorithms that'd make conflicts between the two significantly more likely than within hg and git separately?

Answer (score 4):

you will be fine.

they both (currently) use SHA-1.  since the hash exposed by the API is just the hex representation of that, there can be no additional risk - this follows directly from the properties of a cryptographic hash.

in other words - it doesn't matter what processing is used before the hash is calculated.  once the data go through the hash they become "uniform" in a statistical sense.  processing *afterwards* might affect things, but, as far as i know, there is no post-processing (SHA-1 generates 160 bits or 20 bytes - both git and mercurial hashes are 40 character hex strings, as expected)